# Finite point set has limit points for general topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology

I know that for the standard metric space on $\mathbb{R}$, a finite point set has no limit points. Does this also hold true for a general topological space? If not, is there a counter example?

Answer (score 1):

no it is not, take a set with at least 2 points, with the indiscrete topology

Comment: So for a set $S$ with with at least 2 elements with the indiscrete topology, any point is a limit point of any subset $E$ in the set. This is because the only open sets are the empty set $\phi$ and the whole set $S$, and $S-p$ surely contains all other points in the set $S$ and hence every open neighbourhood of every point intersects every subset in $S$.

Comment: What about the empty set $\phi$? Does it have any limit points?

Answer (score 1):

if the space is $T_1$ it holds, and if a space satisfies that every finite subspace has no limit points then it is $T_1$, so your claim is false in general.